# Отладка конкретного потока

Tags: c#, многопоточность

При отладке создаются 8 потоков, каждый из которых выполняет одну и ту же функцию параллельно. Как можно проследить путь через `F11` от начала и до конца конкретного потока? Чтобы не шли, при нажатии `F11`, все потоки параллельно в отладке, так мало что можно понять.

Comment: Запустить код в 1 потоке, а не в 8, и отлаживать.

Comment: @tym32167 проблема всё старая, когда я запускаю код в 1 потоке, он вычисляет всё правильно, если параллельно, то там при тех же входных параметрах дает разные результаты. Я уже слишком замучался в этом разбираться, да и тут много спрашиваю. В итоге только таким образом можно понять.

Comment: Если в однопоточном режиме все работает хорошо, то проблема в многопоточности. Логгируйте все, что затрагивает проблему, воспроизводите проблему, исследуйте логи.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Например, в Visual Studio вы можете заморозить остальные потоки на время:

[image: картинка]

Не забудьте разморозить их потом! А то один поток будет ожидать окончания другого вечно.

Если другие потоки должны тем временем работать, вы можете поставить условную точку останова, в которой будете проверять ID потока (правая кнопка мыши по точке останова → Conditions...):

[image: здесь хочу, здесь не хочу]

При следующем пробеге, однако, точку останова придётся отредактировать или убрать, так как ID потока может поменяться.

---

Не забывайте, однако, что многопоточная отладка не так проста! Если у вас в коде race condition, то наличие отладчика и точки останова может повлиять на порядок исполнения кода в различных потоках, так что с хорошими шансами ошибка может и не проявиться с пошаговым выполнением и точками останова отладкой. Для того, чтобы бороться с этим, вам придётся добавить логирование (которое влияет на порядок выполнения намного меньше, чем остановка в отладчике). Если и логирование не позволяет локализовать проблему, то приходится использовать метод *пристального взгляда*, просто анализируя код в уме.

Отладка многопоточного пода — одна из самых сложных вещей в программировании.

Comment: ```метод пристального взгляда``` столько раз пользовался, но в первые вижу этому название :)

Comment: Спасибо, буду сейчас отслеживать данным способом)

Comment: @tym32167: У такого хорошего метода должно же быть название :)

Comment: @Fresto: Удачи! У вас непростое задание.

Comment: @VladD учитывая, что я с многопоточностью сталкиваюсь впервые, не самый лучший первый опыт) Но спасибо)